# Como gerar uma nova lista a partir de outra lista em Python?

Tags: python, lista

Estou com dificuldades para realizar operações de listas em Pyhton. Tenho uma lista de valores.

```
frequencia = [1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5, 5.5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 
              19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40,
              41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62,
              63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84,
              85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 120, 150, 200,300,400, 
              500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000]
```

A partir dessa lista quero gerar uma nova lista de valores obtidos aplicando a seguinte fórmula em todos os valores de frequência.

```
at = (7.19 * (10**(-3)) + (6.09/((freq**2)+0.227) + 
     (4.81/(((freq-57)**2)+1.5)))) * freq**2 * (10**(-3))
```

Aqui está o código que estou tentando.

```
frequencia = [1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5, 5.5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 
              19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 
              41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 
              63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 
              85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96,97, 98, 99, 100, 120, 150, 200, 300,400, 
              500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000]
at_seco = []
for i in range(len(frequencia)):
    while len(freq)<len(frequencia):
        freq = frequencia[0]
        freq = freq + 1
        return freq
at = (7.19 * (10**(-3)) + (6.09/((freq**2)+0.227) + 
     (4.81/(((freq-57)**2)+1.5)))) * freq**2 * (10**(-3))
at_seco.append(at)
return at_seco
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que entendi você deseja pegar a lista **frequencia** e aplicar a fórmula...

```
(7.19 * (10**(-3)) + (6.09/((freq**2)+0.227) + (4.81/(((freq-57)**2)+1.5)))) * freq**2 * (10**(-3))
```

... a cada elemento da referida lista.

Pois bem, para você fazer isto você deve iterar sobre a referida lista aplicando a cada valor a referida fórmula.

Desta forma o código pode ser:

```
frequencia = [1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5, 5.5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18,
              19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40,
              41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62,
              63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84,
              85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 120, 150, 200, 300, 400,
              500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000]

at_seco = []
for freq in frequencia:
    at = (7.19 * (10**(-3)) + (6.09/((freq**2)+0.227) + (4.81/(((freq-57)**2)+1.5)))) * freq**2 * (10**(-3))
    at_seco.append(at)

print(at_seco)
```

Observe que o **for** percorrerá a lista **frequencia** e, para cada valor inserido na mesma, será aplicada a referida fórmula.

Posteriormente a nova lista é exibida com auxílio de apenas a função **print**.

**OBSERVAÇÃO:** A palavra reservada **return** só é utilizada para exibir saídas de **funções**. Neste caso, o **return** é desnecessário.

---

Outra forma de resolver esta questão é:

```
frequencia = [1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5, 5.5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18,
              19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40,
              41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62,
              63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84,
              85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 120, 150, 200, 300, 400,
              500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000]


def at(freq):
    return (7.19 * (10**(-3)) + (6.09/((freq**2)+0.227) + (4.81/(((freq-57)**2)+1.5)))) * freq**2 * (10**(-3))


at_seco = [at(i) for i in frequencia]

print(at_seco)
```

Observe que este segundo código é gerado a partir de um **[list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)**. O laço **for** percorre a lista **frequencia** e, para cada valor iterado,  calcula o valor de **at** - que neste caso é gerado por uma função `def` - inserido o valor correspondente na lista **at_seco**.

Comment: Era exatamente essa minha dúvida, muito obrigado